# Numerical Methods - How to solve this equation of the bank interest rate?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, finance, computational-mathematics

I have an interest equation and I need to evaluate the interest increase from certain iterations, using Newton's method.

Eq.:$f(i) = (1-(1-i)^{-10})/i  -1400/182.25$

$(i  -- plan)$
$(0  -- 0.05)$
$(1  -- 0.05106)$
$(2  -- 0.05107)$
...
But when I apply the equation in Matlab, I can not produce similar values. Could someone tell me how I can develop this?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site, then edit your post.  As written, it is hard to discern what the intended equation is for $f(i)$.

Comment: What equation ? You mean $\frac{1-(1\color{red}+i)^{-10}}{i} -1400/182.25\color{blue}{=0}$ ?

Comment: @callculus That is it

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply a numerical method.
You have $\frac{1-(1\color{red}+i)^{-10}}{i} =1400/182.25 $

First you multiply both sides by $(1+i)^{10}$

$\frac{(1+i)^{10}-1}{i} =1400/182.25\cdot (1+i)^{10}$

Then we use that $i=(1+i)-1$

$\frac{(1+i)^{10}-1}{(1+i)-1} =1400/182.25\cdot (1+i)^{10}$

substituting/simplifying: $1+i=q$ and $C=1400/182.25$

$\frac{q^{10}-1}{q-1} =C\cdot q^{10}$

Multiplying by $q-1$

$q^{10}-1 =C\cdot q^{11}-C\cdot q^{10} \qquad |-q^{10}+1$

$0=C\cdot q^{11}-(C+1)\cdot q^{10}+1 \qquad \color{blue}{(1)}$

Now you have a polynomial with degree 11 with the coefficients $C, C+1$ and $1$.

$f(q)=C\cdot q^{11}-(C+1)\cdot q^{10}+1$

Here you can apply the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). You start with

$q_1=q_0-\frac{f(q_0)}{f^{\ '}(q_0)}$, where $x_o$ is the initial value. I assume $i$ is the interest rate. There for $q=1+i$ should  not be far away from $1.05$. This would I use as the initial value: $q_0=1.05$.

But you first can also try out some  values for $q$ at $ \color{blue}{1}$ for a rough estimation of $q$. If $f(q)$ is close to $0$ then you need not so many iteration.

Hint: $f^{\ '}(q)=11\cdot C\cdot q^{10}-10\cdot (C+1)\cdot q^{9}$

Comment: Thank you my friend, for this!

Comment: @RafaNp You´re welcome. For many exercises I used Excel to calculate the iterations steps. The formulas are quite simple.

Comment: @RafaNp, if you are happy with the solution, please accept it so that this question will be closed.